# ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError (using database backend)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

Similar to [ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError but the file actually exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323101/activestoragefilenotfounderror-but-the-file-actually-exists) but using a database backend.

The underlying data appears to be still present in `active_storage_blobs` table. However, Rails just throws a `ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError`. Is there something that can cause Active Storage data to become expired?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data is not actually stored in the database (despite the active storage tables) - the blob is written to disk. My setup (using Capistrano) did not use a common storage location across multiple deployments, so files uploaded in previous deployments become inaccessible after a new deployment. Using a common symlinked location should fix this.